# Are the most of the games requiring me to share my location even really required to get it in regards to the game?

Tags: mobile

After checking the latest update, now even hearthstone requires my location...

I'm curious, is there any reason so many games require my personal data like my location?

Or is this just because (law taken aside not to say beeing ignored) it never hurts to have too much user specific data, than too few, and you never know when you could need to resample the behavior of your users?

Answer (score 3):

Along with Иво Недев's answer, generally games and apps that use location data are for ads, to provide the user with ads more relevant to their location (like for a restaurant in your area). You can easily disallow the use of location by going into your settings, at least on Android, and disabling the specific app's location permission.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the game.

It's quite obvious for games like Pokemon GO, where location is everything.

Some games don't really need it, in some cases its just the developer throwing it in there, just because (I know I've done it)

Hearthstone most likely requires your location so it can match you with players near you and put you both in a convenient server. After all you wouldn't like to wait 20s just for your move to happen, would you?

Comment: the point for hearthstone is valid. but they just need it since the latest patch. and it worked before without aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Advertising, if your at a Wal-Mart Wyatt ads pop up also some games need it like Philemon go some games are run by kidnappers to see where you are I'm not kidding you need to be careful other games usually multiplayer games need it so they know where you are for "local games" these are the most common